# PHP cURL file upload to JSP script fails. Same file uploaded via browser works

Tags: php, jsp, curl

Using PHP/cURL I log into a web site and attempt to upload a file. It returns the error message, "Error: File upload not processed. Please ensure that an applicable excel file in the specified template format is selected for upload."  This error is different from the message I get if I upload from a browser and give it a file of the wrong format (like a .jpg).

If I upload the same excel file through Firefox it works and is accepted by the server.

So how can I make this work through PHP/cURL the way it does with Firefox?

I tried the same upload to my own PHP script and it also works fine.  I also reviewed some relevant questions here and tried various things, none of which made any difference.  I tried with and without the MIME type also with and without options CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

The owner of the web site was not particularly helpful, only telling me that others are doing it.

Below is my code:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/uploadController_u.jsp';

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $curl_referer );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); // Added based on another StackOverflow question
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') ); // Added based on another StackOverflow question

// Tried with and without the MIME type
$post_vars = array( 
'file' => "@/home/someuser/private/eapis-test/mx/Template-test.xls;type=application/vnd.ms-excel",
'submit' => 'Upload file'  );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars );
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Below is the form I am posting to. I did not find any references to form1 in the javascript.

```
<table border="0"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <form action="uploadController_u.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <p>
                <h2>Upload Flight:</h2>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b style="font-size: 90%;">To add a new flight from spreadsheet, </b>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <input name="file" type="file" id="file" align="left" size="36">
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload file"/>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

I tried these headers to better simulate a browser, but to no avail:

```
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
```

Comment: Well the error that you get is pretty informative: `Error: File upload not processed. Please ensure that an applicable excel file in the specified template format is selected for upload.`.  So I think the JSP is performing a set of tests on the uploaded file.  Are you sure that the Excel file that you're sending actually conforms to whatever template they want it to conform to?

Comment: Yes, I can upload the same file through a browser and it works.

Comment: Show the `<form... </form>` from the html. Update your question.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but I notice your form has 'Submit' capitalized but in your curl post it's lower case

Comment: You first have to save the file and then send it with cURL: `$post = array(
        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); `

Answer (score 0):

"Please ensure that an applicable excel file in the specified template format is selected for upload"

Probably nothing to do with your script.  If the destination server is telling the truth, then  the file you're uploading is not to the "specified template format".

If it is, and you're absolutely sure it is, then the error message is incorrect, and the only sane action is to contact whoever administrates the server again.

Comment: Uploading the same file through a browser returns an "upload successful" message.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.  I will contact the admin again.  I haven't lost my sanity yet, but I may soon with this problem!

Comment: Ah yes.  Then, at least you know it's their issue, not yours!  Good luck.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. The web site owner does not seem to have anyone technical enough to help. If I can upload a the same file through a browser, I should be able to make it work through cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Not realy a solution because all your code seems to be correct, but some advice on how to troubleshoot without the help of the server admin.

1. Create a simple upload script yourself and use your script to post the file to your own server. Double check that the file you recieve is 100% equal to the one you send.
2. Although your content type is correct, try using `application/octet-stream` or nothing to see if that changes anything
3. If your are not already, try running a local php server to run your curl script, to make sure there are no IP checks that influence the error.
4. Since your receive a different error when the file type is wrong with JPG, try uploading the JPG with your script to see if you get the same error then. If you get the same error as with the excel file, its mostlikely a security check on the server side.
5. Use a tool like [BURP suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to inspect the actual headers/etc that are being send and try to mimic them with curl. Firebug might work aswell, but personally I prefer Burp when I'm stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you state that the script is working well for your own website and I don't see any errors in the code my guess is that probably you aren't sending enough data or the right one.

When i made a yahoo.com login script I used [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) for Firefox as a proxy to see all the data sent by the browser to the specific webpage, to see if there is some sent data you didn't know about.

Also I would try to remove some specific features from the browser, like the cookies or removing the referer and tring to upload, to understand exactly what wrong/missing thing causes the "Error: File upload not processed. Please ensure that an applicable excel file in the specified template format is selected for upload." error.

I usually use [HackBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/hackbar/) (Firefox) to remove the referrer and [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) to disable Cookies, Javascript, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $target_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/file.php';
        $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');
        $post = array('extra' => '123456','file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo $result;
?>
```